# Best way to store a large amount of data in the browser to retain and use across other areas of the application with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Evening All,

My project is a simple Javascript application, that takes income and expenses, displays them on the spending page and then uses those values to calculate the overall budget on the home page.

The data I think I would need to store is as follows:

- The input values on the spending page
- The row that is added to the UI after the item is added (So that the users spending will stay on screen even after a page refresh)
- Possibly the calculation for the budget so that I can then use this to calculate and update the budget and then update the UI on the home page

I know that the best option is to use the localStorage method and not cookies. I understand examples of this method, but I simply cannot figure out how to apply this to all of the data I need to retain.

I know that potentially I could create a function in my global controller and then call this function after all the other functions have gone away and grabbed the needed data and updated the UI on the spending page. But I just cannot seem to get it to work.

I also appreciate that a better way to do this would probably be to store the users data in a database like SQL and then serve it up with something like C#. But I'm building this application to practice JS so I want to try and keep it purely Javascript based.

**I am yet to build the calculation and update budget functions, I know how to do this. I just do not know how I will then update the UI on the home page and retain that after refresh, so I wanted to figure storing the data before I begin building that functionality**

Please see below images to hopefully better illustrate what the application does and what I am hoping to achieve by implementing this functionality. 
[image]

**Once you input a description,value and select item type. A row is added to the UI with this information. I want to retain this in the variable and on the UI after page refresh. I will also need to use this information at a later stage to update the total budget on the home page.**
[image]

**The budget calculation will come into place on this page and update the value accordingly. The income and expense boxes will also update accordingly to the data on the spending page. Again I want to retain this information and the UI after a page refresh. I also need to allow this page to access data stored in the spending page.**

Please see code below.

Apologies if you don't really need the HTML just thought it may help understand how it all works.

**Home page HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Money Load</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h1 class="title"><strong>Money Load</strong> </h1><image src = 'images/logo.png' class = "logo"></image></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="spending.html">Spending</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class = "container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col budgetRow">
<h2 class ="text-center">Available Budget in </h2> 
<h3 class="text-center">£0</h3>       
</div>
</div>
<div class="row  incomeRow text-center">
        <div class="col">
<h3>INCOME</h3>
<h4>+ £0</h4>
</div>    
</div>
<div class="row  expensesRow text-center">
        <div class="col amount">
                <h3>EXPENSES</h3>
                <h4>- £0</h4>   
            </div>

</div>

</div>    
<script src = "index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Spending page HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Spending</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="spending.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h1 class="title"><strong>Money Load</strong> </h1><image src = 'images/logo.png' class = "logo"></image></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                              </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="spending.html">Spending</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row text-center subHeader">
                    <div class="col">
                            <h2>Add Transaction</h2>       
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="row text-center inputRow">
                    <div class="col input">
             <input type="text" class="form-control addDescription" placeholder="Enter a description">       
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center inputRow2">
            <div class="col input2">
            <input type="number" class = "form-control addAmount" placeholder="Value">        
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row text-center transactionTypeRow">
                    <div class="col">
                            <select class ="addType">
                                <label>Type</label>
                                    <option value="inc">Income +</option>
                                    <option value="exp">Expense -</option>
                                  </select>     
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="row text-center submitButtonRow">
                    <div class="col input2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addCostButton">Add</button>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="row CostsRow">
                        <div class="col-6">
                <h3 class="incomeTitle"><strong>INCOME</strong></h3>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                        <h3 class="expensesTitle"><strong>EXPENSES</strong></h3>        
                        </div>
                </div>


                <div class="incomeList">
                        <!--
                <div class = "incomeCostsDetail" id="income-0">
<div class="itemDescription incomeDescription"><strong>Salary</strong></div>
<div class="itemValue incomeValue"><strong>+ 1400</strong></div>
<button class="btn btn-danger itemDelete  incomeDelete"></button>
</div>
-->
</div>

<div class="expenseList">
        <!--
<div class = "expenseCostsDetail" id="expense-0">
        <div class="itemDescription expenseDescription"><strong>Food</strong></div>
        <div class="itemValue expenseValue"><strong>- 200</strong></div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger itemDelete expenseDelete"></button>
        </div>
        -->
</div> 

                </div>














    </div>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
//Budget Controller
var budgetController = (function () {

var Expense  = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
};

var Income  = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
};


var data = {
    allItems: {
    inc : [],
    exp : []
},
Totals: {
    inc : 0,
    exp : 0
}

};

return {
    additem: function(type,des,val) {
        var newItem, ID;

        //create new item id
        if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
        } else {
            ID = 0;
        }
        // create new item based on type
        if(type === "inc"){

newItem = new Income(ID, des, val)

} else if (type === "exp") {

    newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val)

}

//push it into the data structure
data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

// return the new element
return newItem;
    },

    calculateBudget: function() {
//calculate total income and expenses 

//calculate the budget: income - expenses

//calculate the percentage of income that we spent

    }
};

})();

//UI Controller
var UIController = (function() {


return {
getinput: function () {

    return {
        description : document.querySelector(".addDescription").value,
        value : parseFloat(document.querySelector(".addAmount").value),
        type : document.querySelector(".addType").value//either + or -
    };


},

addListItem: function (obj, type){
var html, newHtml, element;
    // Create HTML string with placeholder text
    if (type === "inc"){
        element = '.incomeList';
   html = '<div class = "incomeCostsDetail" id="income-%id%"><div class="itemDescription incomeDescription"><strong>%description%</strong></div><div class="itemValue incomeValue"><strong>+ £%value%</strong></div><button class="btn btn-danger itemDelete  incomeDelete"></button>   </div>';
} else if (type === "exp"){
    element = '.expenseList';
   html ='<div class = "expenseCostsDetail" id="expense-%id%"><div class="itemDescription expenseDescription"><strong>%description%</strong></div><div class="itemValue expenseValue"><strong>- £%value%</strong></div><button class="btn btn-danger itemDelete expenseDelete"></button></div>';
};

   //Replace the placeholder text with actual data 
 newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
 newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
 newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);

    //Insert the HTML into the DOM
document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
},

//clears input description and value after amount entered
clearFields: function() {

    document.querySelector(".addDescription").value = "";
    document.querySelector(".addAmount").value = "";
    document.querySelector(".addDescription").focus();
}

};

})();

//Global Controller
var controller = (function (budgetCtrl, UICtrl){

    var setupEventListeners = function () {

        document.querySelector(".addCostButton").addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

            if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){
                ctrlAddItem();
            }

        });
    };

var updateBudget = function () {
    //1.Calculate the budget

    //2.Return the budget

    //3.Display the budget on the UI
}

var ctrlAddItem = function () {
    var input, newItem;
    //1. Get the field input data
input = UICtrl.getinput();
//2. Prevents user adding item with no value

if(input.description!=="" && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0 ){
    //3. Add the item to the budget controller
newItem = budgetCtrl.additem(input.type, input.description, input.value);
    //4. Add a new item to the UI
UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);

//5. clear the fields
UICtrl.clearFields();

//6. Calculate and update budget 
updateBudget();

} else {
    alert("Please enter a valid transaction description or value!");
}

};

return {
    init: function() {
        console.log("application has started");
        setupEventListeners();
    }
};

})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: LocalStorage should be fine - just store and load all the data as a large JSON text. If you are looking for really huge amounts of data, go for IndexedDb.

Comment: Thank you Bergi but this is the problem I don't fully understand how to achieve that in the context of this application. What steps should I take.

Comment: Just make the `init` method load the data, and call a `save()` method everytime you change something (or when a button is clicked or whatever behaviour you want). I can't see any code in your application that attempts to do this yet?

Comment: So use localstorage set in the save method and localstorage get in the init method?

Comment: You should also have a look at the IndexedDB option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: @orangejuice Precisely that. And `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse`.

Comment: In order to use a JSON text file will I not also need to implement node.js?

Comment: I've looked at this and it has helped a lot so thank you. But I still can't figure out how to properly implement it, all I ever get is undefined returned from the save function. Please could you give me an example of how I could implement this in the application?